# XPath Help Required

Tags: xml, xpath

I need some help with figuring out `XPath` expressions to locate specific information from an XML excerpt.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE example EXAMPLE "example.dtd">
<example mode="server">
    <listen>
        <address>9.21.1.33</address>
        <address>9.4.43.207</address>
        <port proto="tcp">9786</port>
    </listen>
    <max-clients>16</max-clients>
    <turn-clock unit="seconds">40</turn-clock>
</example>
```

Then from that I am trying to figure out the following:

1. The set of all address elements
2. The value of the unit attribute of the turn-clock element
3. The mode attribute of the root element
4. The value of the second example element
5. The value of the max-clients element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `//address`
2. `//turn-clock/@unit`
3. `//@mode`
4. `//turn-clock/text()`
5. `//max-clients/text()`

Comment: So it wouldn't be this for number 1? example/listen/address, or is the // a shortcut for excluding that? Thanks!

Comment: Its a shortcut to look at element with that name.

Comment: Last question and I will. Just want to be sure I understand this all correctly. If I were to find the value of the second address element, would it look like this? //address[2]

Comment: Thats correct. Just google for an online xpath editor to test your syntax.

Comment: Actually, `//turn-clock/@unit` does not return the _value_ of the `@unit` attribute - it returns  whole attribute nodes. Also, paths that avoid the `//` axis are usually preferred, e.g. `/example/listen/address`.